# Force W7 Shutdown/Reboot

Tags: windows-7

When I go to reboot my laptop (one that I access remotely often), a lot of the time it will hang and a process will completely prevent it from shutting down or rebooting. Is there any registry hack or anything that I can throw on my Windows 7 system that will force those programs to close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a command script like this..

`@echo off

shutdown -f -s -t 0`

And save this script on desktop with the name of `shutdown.cmd`. And this will shutdown your PC immediate.

And if you are using it remotely then you can try the command

`Shutdown -f -s -m \\ComputerName`

Or you can set the time to shutdown your remote PC too...

`Shutdown -f -s -m -t 0 \\ComputerName`

Replace the `-s` with `-r` to restart the PC.

Replace the 0 with your time limit. For more information see this [article](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_shutdown_command.htm). You also see [create shortcut for shutdown](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61294-shut-down-computer-shortcut-create.html?filter).

Comment: Instead if creating a batch for, just create a new shortcut with the shutdown command. You can also get rid of the black flash, and choose an icon easier

Comment: @Luke good idea to get rid of from black flash. :)

Answer (score 4):

Registry setting to auto-end tasks at shutdown: Type `regedit` in run command and navigate to following path

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Desktop > create string key called AutoEndTasks >` set value to 1

WARNING: this will always shut down Windows, even if an application is open with unsaved changes.

Comment: This solution doesn't work!

Comment: Since you are not the original poster, your issue should be submitted as a new question, with a link to this question, saying something like "I tried that suggestion, but it didn't work", and explain what did or didn't happen. You can check if the Registry key was setup correctly with this DOS command: reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v AutoEndTasks

Comment: I had the exact same question and found this thread so I though better not to post a duplicate. That command shows the value to be set as 1.

Comment: Is the 2nd column REG_SZ?

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` and the second line `AutoEndTasks    REG_SZ    1`

Comment: The following page suggests some additional registry settings that might help. It even has a .reg file that you can download and run to make those changes for you. http://www.sparkmylife.com/auto-end-tasks-while-going-for-proper-shutdown.html

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me to avoid pop-up with buttons `Force shut down` or `Cancel`:

1. Set registry keys:

   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System` add key: `AllowBlockingAppsAtShutdown` with dword value: `1`.
   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control` add key: `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` with string value: `1`.
   - `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop` add key: `AutoEndTasks` with string value: `1`.
2. Reboot.

It may be however dangerous not to give enough time for services or applications to shut down gracefully.

[Here](http://www.sparkmylife.com/auto-end-tasks-while-going-for-proper-shutdown.html) the following is also proposed: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`, key name:`ClearPageFileAtShutdown`, dword value: `1`. It is not needed for my Windows 7 to be shut down without any popups and furthermore, setting that key may result in very long shut downs.

If that does not work, try also: `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop` with key name `WaitToKillAppTimeout` and string value: `1`.